# Can't load JQuery data time picker in ajax loaded div

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need to load data time picker .appendDtpicker() on a input which is in an ajax loaded div.

This is the js code i'm trying to implement:

```
$(document).on('click', "#start_date_q", function(){
        $("#start_date_q").appendDtpicker({"dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD h:m","minuteInterval": 15,"closeOnSelected": true,"calendarMouseScroll": false}); 
        });
```

and this is the html i get from an ajax call earlier:

```
<div id="ajax results"><input type="text" id="start_date_q" name="start_date_q" value="'></div>
```

I'm geting this error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'appendDtpicker'
```

I tried also this JS code:

```
function select_date(type){

        $("#"+type).appendDtpicker({"dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD h:m","minuteInterval": 15,"closeOnSelected": true,"calendarMouseScroll": false}); 


     }
```

and html:

```
<div id="ajax results"><input type="text" id="start_date_q" name="start_date_q" value="" onclick="select_date('start_date_q')"></div>
```

The same error is displayed.

When i implement the same JS on another input(not ajax loaded), it does show the datetime picker.

I've used this JS plugin: https://github.com/mugifly/jquery-simple-datetimepicker
Please anybody help me!

Comment: Are you sure jquery and jquery-simple-datetimepicker are loaded?

Comment: just put <head> tag or code where you are laoding both jquery.js and query-simple-datetimepicker.js

Comment: Also tried this, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure that your script is being loaded.  Use chrome or ie developer tools to check. Also makesure the https://github.com/mugifly/jquery-simple-datetimepicker plugin is referenced from your page after the jquery reference.

```
<script src="pathtojquery"></script>
<script src="pathtoplugin"></script>
```

Comment: The script is loaded when i load the page. The problem is when i load (with ajax) the div where's the input id='start_date_q'. When i click in the input it shows that error on console. I have used Jquery UI datapicker before in the same situation and it does work. But I need a data time picker.

Comment: @rakela are you able to create this in jsfiddle and put a link up so i can have a look

Comment: I'm not sure i can create this situation on jsfiddle. It's such a complicated situation. 
However, how can I recall the script after the div is ajax loaded (before i click on input)? I tried  $.getScript(), but didn't work.

Comment: I tried this one:
`$(document).on('click', "#start_date_q", function(){
            alert('ok');
            $.getScript("js/jquery.simple-dtpicker.js", function() {
           alert('ok1');
           $("#start_date_q").appendDtpicker({"dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD h:m","minuteInterval": 15,"closeOnSelected": true,"calendarMouseScroll": false}); 
        });
           });`
I get both alerts, but i still get the same error message. :(

Comment: Please can you suggest me any jQyery date time picker plugin? Like this one i'm trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', "#start_date_q", 
    function(){ 
        alert('ok'); 
        $.getScript("js/jquery.simple-dtpicker.js", function() { 
            alert('ok1');
            setTimeout( function() { 
                $("#start_date_q").appendDtpicker(
                    {"dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD h:m",
                    "minuteInterval": 15,
                    "closeOnSelected": true,
                    "calendarMouseScroll": false
                }); 
            }, 100);
        });
});
```

Comment: I tried this.
 The same error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'appendDtpicker' `

Comment: this does means that you do not have jquery-simple-datetimepicker.js script loaded. please load it just after jquery.js file

Comment: I've loaded id right after jquery.js. I don't understand why i det the error.